# Visual Studio 2010 only creates Team Project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I want to share my Problem. In Visual Studio 2010, In File menu I have only options of Creating Team Project and Connect to team Project. I was using Team Foundation Server but now I want to create project on C# and develop Web services for the ASP.Net Project. What should I do to get options of New Project and Open Project only. I want to get rid of Team Project.

Steps to reproduce the problem:
1. Click File|New
2. Note that 'Project' is disabled; only 'Team Project' is enabled
3. CLick File|Open
4. Note that only 'Team Project' is enabled.

How can I create or open non-Team Foundation Server projects?

Comment: When you click on File > New , you dont get option of Project ?
Try pressing ctrl + shift + N

Comment: Thanks alot:) it can create new project by using Ctrl+Shift+N.   I want to this option in file drop down how can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've got a corrupted VS configuration, or that it's set to behave like it's the Team Foundation Explorer Shell, which only offers Team Foundation options, and not anything else.

Do this:

<kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Import and Export Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Reset all settings</kbd> > <kbd>Next</kbd> > <kbd>General Development Settings</kbd> (or C# or VB or whatever you like).